# How do I insert blank leaves on a probability tree diagram using TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, tikz-trees, trees, statistics

I have the below code that generates a basic probability tree.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
grow=right,
level distance=3cm,
level 1/.style = {sibling distance=12em},
level 2/.style = {sibling distance=8em},
%
every node/.style = {rounded corners,
                     draw, align=center,
                     top color=white, bottom color=white}
                    ]
\node {}
    child { node {$T_3$}
      edge from parent node[above] { $\frac{1}{1+l}$ }}
    child { node {$T_2$}
      edge from parent node[above] { $\frac{1}{1+l}$ }}
    child { node {$\vdots$}}
    child { node {$T_1$}
      edge from parent node[above] { $\frac{1}{1+l}$ }}
    child { node {$T_0$}
      edge from parent node[above] { $\frac{1}{1+l}$ } };
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: code result]

Instead of the standard line and box around the `\vdots`, how do I remove this so that the `\vdots` are just free standing (implying multiple "hidden" branches in the diagram)?

Comment: Welcome. Just disable any action you don't want anymore (`draw=none`, `fill=none`, **`shade=none`**, etc.) You can also use the undocumented `path only` that disables all actions: `child { node [path only] {$\vdots$}}`

Comment: Welcome. // Please try yourself: your posted code can't compile when copied. Kindly add the missing parts to make it compile. // And please add a screenshot of your codes result. // Thank you

Comment: @MS-SPO Has the system changed? I didn't think new users could add images, though I think they can include a link and somebody else can make it active?

Comment: @cfr, good question: as far as I know and have seen here, even new users can post images, at least when writing a question. Modifying a posted question may still be somewhat limited, restricted by reputations, which I can't verify at the moment. However, using the question-interface seems to remain a challenge here and there,unless you understood some of its features ;-)

Comment: @MS-SPO Maybe you're right. I answered questions anonymously on here for a bit and I don't remember not being able to post output.

Answer (score 1):

With credits to @Qrrbrbirbel for pointing it out in [his comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/694974/how-do-i-insert-blank-leaves-on-a-probability-tree-diagram-using-tikz?noredirect=1#comment1725130_694974) and to @cfr for completing your code snippet, here's the appraoch spelled out for you. The relevant line of code is:

```
    child { node[draw=none,minimum width=3em] {$\vdots$}}% <<<
```

- `draw=none` simply doesn't draw the nodes shape
- `minimum width=3em` may be useful to widen the nodes text field, which moves the dots a bit to the right (1em is the width of a single `m` character; you can also use mm, pt, cm, in, etc.)

[image: result]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
grow=right,
level distance=3cm,
level 1/.style = {sibling distance=12em},
level 2/.style = {sibling distance=8em},
%
every node/.style = {rounded corners,
                     draw, align=center,
                     top color=white, bottom color=white}
                    ]
\node {}
    child { node {$T_3$}
      edge from parent node[above] { $\frac{1}{1+l}$ }}
    child { node {$T_2$}
      edge from parent node[above] { $\frac{1}{1+l}$ }}
    child { node[draw=none,minimum width=3em] {$\vdots$}}% <<<
    child { node {$T_1$}
      edge from parent node[above] { $\frac{1}{1+l}$ }}
    child { node {$T_0$}
      edge from parent node[above] { $\frac{1}{1+l}$ } };
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

---

Follow-up from comment: to modify the lye, modify the `child`'s option, like so:

```
    child[dotted, red] { node[draw=none,minimum width=3em,black] {$\vdots$}}% <<<
```

which will result in a dotted red line AND black node-text.
[image: res]

If you want both in red, just do:

```
child[dotted, red] { node[draw=none,minimum width=3em] {$\vdots$}}% <<<
```

Comment: Thanks for this - definitely better than what I had. Out of interest, do you know how to remove the line (or make it dotted itself)?

Comment: See my answer (follow-up)

Comment: Hiya, thanks again for this. sorry to pester again but this makes every subsequent node along the tree dotted. Is there a command for a solid line that I could use (in place of none or dotted) that forces it to appear "normal". Thanks!

Comment: Look for every node in the pgfmanual. (And don't forget to accept my answer, if it suits your needs ;-)

Comment: Hi, I've spent the last 40-ish minutes reading through pgfmanual but there isn't anything that answers my question there. It's clearly a very interesting document but it contains A LOT of material. Searching for "every node" gives over a hundred hits; related terms to my problem also give similar quagmires...

Comment: So, be a Digital Native, improve your finding skill (everydummy can search, fewer can find), e.g. via this site: https://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=tikz+every+line+dashed, or via https://www.google.com/search?q=pgrmanual+dashed+every ;-)